# How can I read ObjC pointer to pointer (**) using Fida Javascript APIs?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, frida

This is my index.js

```
const className = 'NSURLConnection'
const methodName = 'sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:'

Interceptor.attach(ObjC.classes[className][`+ ${methodName}`].implementation, {
  onEnter: function (args) {
    const response = new ObjC.Object(args[3])
    console.log('URL', response.URL())
  }
})
```

`args[3]` should be a `NSURLResponse`. If I understood correctly, based on what is written inside the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnection/1411393-sendsynchronousrequest?language=objc), response arg should be a pointer to a pointer. When I try to log response url, everything breaks. How can I access the object like I would do with a normal pointer?

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to dereference a pointer like args[3] in Frida you can simply execute `readPointer()` from Frida [NativePointer](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#nativepointer) API:

```
args[3].readPointer()
```

Unfortunately you are trying to hook the parameter `response` which is an `Out parameter for the URL`. That means it will contain the result after the method has been executed. Thus accessing it in `onEnter` will not work. You have to do it in `onLeave`:

```
Interceptor.attach(ObjC.classes[className][`+ ${methodName}`].implementation, {
  onEnter: function (args) {
    this.savedArg = args[3]; // save argument for onLeave
  },
  onLeave: function (retval) {
    const responsePtr = prt(this.savedArg).readPointer(); // ptr just to make sure
    const response = new ObjC.Object(responsePtr);
    console.log('URL', response.URL());
  }
})
```

Not sure if this code will work, just give it a try...